# Getting warning message while using PopoverController on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have two view controllers – AViewController and BViewController. BViewController's view is used for AViewController's subview:

```
BViewController *bViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"basic"];
[self.view addSubview: bViewController.view];
```

...so that I can display BViewController's data on AViewController but handle data in BViewController. In BViewController I use a UIPopOverController when I press some button on it, displaying it like this:

```
_popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_popContentView];

[_popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:sender.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

I'm getting this warning message:

> presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are showing `UIPopoverController`  in a subview . Show `UIPopoverController` in viewcontroller .